# Remove a line of characters in a String with Swift

Tags: swift, string, character

I read many questions about removing characters from a string. But none of them resolved my issue.

**I have this string:**

```
"\"iconCls\":X.net.RM.getIcon(\"BulletWhite\")"
```

**I want to replace this part:**

```
"X.net.RM.getIcon(\"BulletWhite\")"
```

**By this (double quotes in fact):**

```
"\"\""
```

**I use this code:**

```
let dataString = "\"iconCls\":X.net.RM.getIcon(\"BulletWhite\")"
let newString = dataString?.replacingOccurrences(of: "X.net.RM.getIcon(\"BulletWhite\")" as String, with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
```

But it doesn't work. I can replace all characters until I want to replace strings containing parentheses.Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use options or range for this.

```
let str = "\"iconCls\":X.net.RM.getIcon(\"BulletWhite\")"
let replace = "X.net.RM.getIcon(\"BulletWhite\")"
let replaceBy = "\"\""

let newString = str.replacingOccurrences(of: replace, with: replaceBy)
```

Comment: But how can I convert it to remove backslash before double quotes? Is this an encoding format?

Comment: @greenpoisononeTV There are no backslashes in the actual string. There's nothing to remove.

Comment: @rmaddy Of course there are backslashes before all double quotes when I print the string.

Comment: @greenpoisononeTV That's just Xcode's debug output. If you put that string in a label, for example, there would be no backslashes. To be clear, I am referring to the values in the code posted in your question and the answers.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the `.regularExpression` option but you are not actually using a regular expression.

Change:

```
.regularExpression
```

to:

```
[]
```

This gives the result you want:

```
let dataString = "\"iconCls\":X.net.RM.getIcon(\"BulletWhite\")"
let newString = dataString.replacingOccurrences(of: "X.net.RM.getIcon(\"BulletWhite\")" as String, with: "", options: [], range: nil)
```

Output:

> "icnCls":

Even simpler:

```
let newString = dataString.replacingOccurrences(of: "X.net.RM.getIcon(\"BulletWhite\")" as String, with: "")
```